# Set ReplyToQMgr and ReplyToQ in Apache Camel reout to receive COA using IBM MQ

Tags: java, apache-camel, ibm-mq

I am using Apache Camel and IBM MQ to send messages. I need to receive COA when a message gets delivered to a remote queue. The general picture looks like this:
[image]

When the message reaches msg_q2 queue, I should receive the COA back. So, the problem is that I am not able to set the QMGR_REM as reply-to queue manager, which is supposed to produce COA.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/8.0?topic=messages-reply-queue-queue-manager

I tried setting JMS_IBM_MQMD_xxx headers, but for some reason those  headers either get omitted or ignored (by Camel?), and the message fails to be put on the queue with the reason that the reply-to queue is not specified. Also, I tried setting JMSReplyTo header as `queue://reply-to-qmgr/reply-to-q`. In this case the `queue://` part gets removed, and the rest is simply set as a reply-to queue name.

I am relatively new to Apache Camel, and IBM MQ, so any input would be very appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to set QMGR_REM as the reply-to-QMgr? Why not instead ensure that routing from QMGR_REM back to QMGR_LOC exists so that a message destined for a queue (replyToQ1) on QMGR_LOC can be delivered. Then your application doesn't need to do anything complicated.

Comment: Because QMGR_REM owns replyToQ2, and a queue manager is the one responsible for generating COA (and other report messages). I need to have this implemented to ensure that a message is successfully put onto msg_q2 queue.

Comment: I don't think you understand how MQ works.  If you create a **_Queue Manager Alias_** for 'QMGR_LOC' in queue manager 'QMGR_REM' then MQ will automatically flow the messages including COA & COD back to the correct queue if you specify RemoteQMgrName of 'QMGR_LOC' and RemoteQName of 'ReplyToQ1'.  It's that simple.  You are overly complicating things.

Answer (score 2):

In your application, just provide the name of your ReplyToQ as `replyToQ1` and leave the ReplyToQMgr field blank. The queue manager will fill it in with the local queue manager name `QMGR_LOC` for you.

And on `QMGR_REC` do one of the following:-

1. If your transmission queue for the channel from `QMGR_REM` to `QMGR_LOC` is named exactly `QMGR_LOC`, you have nothing further to do. When `QMGR_REM` comes to put the COA onto queue `replyToQ1` on queue manager `QMGR_LOC`, it will resolve it to the transmission queue that has the name `QMGR_LOC` and the channel will deliver it.
2. If your transmission queue for the channel from `QMGR_REM` to `QMGR_LOC` is not named exactly `QMGR_LOC`, then make the following definition on `QMGR_REM`:

```
DEFINE QREMOTE(QMGR_LOC) RNAME(' ') RQMNAME(QMGR_LOC) +
       XMITQ(your-transmission-queue-going-to-QMGR_LOC)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, basically by trial and error I figured out that adding `mdWriteEnabled=true` property on`CamelJmsDestinationName` Camel header made it working as I need.

The code is something like this:

`route.setHeader("CamelJmsDestinationName", "queue:///msg_q1?targetClient=1&mdWriteEnabled=true")`

Then I set reply-to queue manager via MQMD property

`route.setHeader("JMS_IBM_MQMD_ReplyToQMgr", "QMGR_REM")`

and reply-to queue

`route.setHeader("JMSReplyTo", "replyToQ2")`

Comment: I have to add here that this is not the recommended way to use ReplyQ's. You are complicating your application and your configuration. Please see the comments on your question and the other answer provided. You application is now reliant on specific configuration on a remote queue manager when it shouldn't need to be. Imagine this scaled up for multiple different application and multiple different queue managers?

Comment: @MoragHughson One benefit of this is you only need to give the responding app permission to the QREMOTE not the XMITQ.  Imagine you had two multi tenant apps on QMGR_REM and QMGR_LOC where multiple apps on QMGR_REM need to respond to apps on QMGR_LOC,  by giving the responding app permission to the XMITQ you can't easily limit each app on QMGR_REM to only those queues it is intended to PUT to.

Comment: @JoshMc - if you want to ensure those two multi tenant apps don't get in each others way, surely they would not be sharing a channel either? Remember by giving the responding app permission to the replyQ you have to do that for EVERY replyQ. It doesn't scale, and it will be hopeless if you ever want to add more queue managers and move to clustering.

Comment: @MoragHughson Without using different ReplyToQmgrs how would you suggest splitting replys to two different channels?

Comment: Repltoqmgr aliases at both ends

Comment: @MoragHughson this can get complicated as well but is a good option to consider.  Thank you for the feedback.